# UIInterfaceOrientation of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I tried checking the UIInterfaceOrientation of the current presented view controller and for some reason it always returns landscape.

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
            if (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
                self.scrollView_.colMargin = 50;
            } else {
                self.scrollView_.colMargin = 130;
            }
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the orientation as follows:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if( orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ) ...
```

Comment: are you locked in landscape mode? have you set the device to be able to rotate? There are a million things that could be preventing it but I assure you the code above works wonderfully :)

Answer (score 1):

From the iOS UIDevice Class Reference:

**orientation**

Returns the physical orientation of the device. (read-only)

Discussion

The value of this property **always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled** by calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.

So you need to do something like:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

and then don't forget to

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

when you viewDidUnload

Answer (score 0):

Casting is not magic. The status bar orientation my use different values than that of the interface orientation. Use the current view controllers `self.interfaceOrientation` property instead.

Comment: same thing it always leads to portrait